# What's the difference between "fideos" and "tallarines"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I know that they both refer to noodles, but would they be different kinds of noodles? For instance, one might be long and thin, while the other might be flat and wide?

Comment: http://www.deperu.com/abc/diferencias-significado/4007/diferencia-entre-fideos-tallarines-y-espaguetis, De todas formas te digo como lo diferenciamos en Cuba, los fideos son los que usan para la sopa, por lo general son mas delgado que los espaguetis, y los tallarines son como los espaguites pero aplastados

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto me imagino que sea distinto depende de la región, te explico en Cuba como se conocen.

Los fideos son los que usamos para la sopa, son mucho más delgado que los espaguetis.

[image]

Los tallarines son de forma aplastada

[image]

Y los espaguetis

[image]

Por lo menos así es en Cuba como se conocen.

Comment: Efectivamente lo mismo en España.

Comment: Sin embargo en Argentina llaman fideo a prácticamente cualquier tipo de pasta.

Answer (score 1):

In Spain, at least in my region, Andalucía, it's quite different.

"Tallarines" is a type of pasta long and flat, but we referred that only in the asiatic case. In other cases, we used the italian word "tagliatelle".

For "Fideos" we understand the kind of pasta you use in a soup. Usually they are tiny and short:

http://www.cubadebate.cu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Fideos-AA.jpg

For the long and thing kind we use "Espaguetis".

The answer to your question will depend on the region you want to go.

Comment: curioso el sitio de la foto es de Cuba

Comment: ¡Es verdad! Jajaja

Answer (score -1):

In Chile "fideos" are as described in the other answers, but we use the word "tallarines" to mean spaghetti or any long pasta